# SKTransition crossFadeWithDuration no longer works

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I am having trouble using the `SKTransaction` object `crossFadeWithDuration`.

It used to fade a new `SKScene` in on top of the current `SKScene` perfectly for me, but now it is working more like the fadeWithDuration object, leaving a greyish gap in between two SKScenes.

I feel like this difference happened with a recent update, but I did not notice it until now. I am simply calling this method with a UIButton press:

```
    self.skView.presentScene(Puzzle1(size: (self.view?.bounds.size)!), transition: SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(2.0))
```

Has anyone else had this problem or know any solution/workaround for that?

Comment: There seems to be some bug related to that. I remember seeing a similar question a few weeks back. Anyway, just to confirm the function is just getting called once(use a break point or print something at that point).

Comment: Thanks Harikrishnan, I have tried many methods to see if it is getting called twice but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you did `self.skView` and not `self.scene?.view?.presentScene also when transitioning to a scene do this 
    let Scene = Puzzle1(size : self.size)
Scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
self.scene?.view?.presentScene(Scene, transition: SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(2.0))`

Comment: Aneesh, this does not work either. I have also tried `self.view?.presentScene(Puzzle2(size: (self.view?.bounds.size)!), transition: SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(2.0))` and also your method but without the `.scene?` as well. I have found that the crossFade only works in iOS 8xx version but not 7 or 9.

Comment: Hmm... could you maybe send me your whole class/code ? so i can see the error?